Counting blank cells by arrayformula
I would like an arrayformula in B1 that calculates for every cell in column B how many empty cells I have in the previous rows in column A, including the current row.
I wasn't able to achieve this even with ChatGPT or Claude Sonnet...

Please provide data,you can read this guide. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Use scan(), like this:
=scan(0, A1:A, lambda(a, c, a + isblank(c)))

See scan().

Welcome to the SCAN() function! But I remain curious about the use of ARRAYFORMULA() in this contest... Has anyone some ideas?

The formula I gave you is an array formula that fills the whole column in one go. It is unclear why you would need another way to solve the same problem. Please ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.

For posterity, here's how to do the same with arrayformula() and countifs(): =arrayformula(countifs(A1:A, "", row(A1:A), "<=" & row(A1:A)))
